# Advice using the pivot_longer function to create two columns from multiple original columns

Tags: r

I was wondering if people coudld please help me. This is probably a simple issue, but I can't get passed it. If you look at my code, I have several variables of interest, Big0.7:Small0.9 and then AttractOne:AttractSix.

```
  ptn Condition Big0.7 X_AttractONE Med0.7 AttractTWO Small0.7 AttractTHREE Big0.9 AttractFOUR Med0.9 AttractFIVE Small0.9 AttractSIX SECScore G.Health
1   1         1      2            5      2          5        1            5      2           5      1           5        2          5     72.8        6
2   2         2      3            4      2          5        3            4      2           5      1           2        1          4     79.8        6
3   3         2      2            4      3          4        3            4      2           4      1           3        2          4     48.8        7
4   4         2      5            1      1          4        1            4      1           4      1           3        1          4     55.4        5
5   5         2      3            4      3          4        3            4      2           4      1           4        2          4     61.3        6
6   6         1      2            4      2          4        2            4      2           4      2           4        2          4     45.4        6
```

What I'm trying to do is change this data from wide to long format, so that Big0.7:Big0.9 all occupy one columna and AttractOne:AttractSix all occupy another.

I've managed to do this for the Big0.7:Big0.9, but I can't fathom how to do it for both of them at the same time - perhaps as I don't quite understand the concept of names_sep or names_patern.

```
maybe %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(Big0.7, Med0.7, Small0.7, Big0.9, Med0.9, Small0.9), names_to= "PreferenceRate", values_to = "count")
```

If someone could please help, I would be grateful. This is my first post, so apologies for any inadequacies, and, I also don't know how best to post my data so I hope this is also okay.

Liam

Comment: Can you *show* expected output?

Comment: A quick solution would be to reorder your columns, then call in the cols =... select(Big0.7, Med0.7, Small0.7, Big0.9, Med0.9, Small0.9, everything() %>% pivot_longer(cols = Big0.7:Small0.9)

Answer (score 0):

Make `Big0.x`,`Med0.x`,`Small0.x` similar to `Attractx`, then use the special variable `.value` with `names_pattern`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  rename('BMSONE'=Big0.7, 'AttractONE'=X_AttractONE, 'BMSTWO'=Med0.7,'BMSTHREE'=Small0.7,'BMSFOUR'=Big0.9,'BMSFIVE'=Med0.9,'BMSSIX'=Small0.9) %>% 
  pivot_longer(BMSONE:AttractSIX, names_to = c('.value','set'), names_pattern = "(BMS|Attract)(.*)")

# A tibble: 36 x 7
     ptn Condition SECScore G.Health set     BMS Attract
   <int>     <int>    <dbl>    <int> <chr> <int>   <int>
 1     1         1     72.8        6 ONE       2       5
 2     1         1     72.8        6 TWO       2       5
 3     1         1     72.8        6 THREE     1       5
 4     1         1     72.8        6 FOUR      2       5
 5     1         1     72.8        6 FIVE      1       5
 6     1         1     72.8        6 SIX       2       5
 7     2         2     79.8        6 ONE       3       4
 8     2         2     79.8        6 TWO       2       5
 9     2         2     79.8        6 THREE     3       4
10     2         2     79.8        6 FOUR      2       5
# … with 26 more rows
```